# Regular expression for url matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a text field have value `http://localhost/Send/test.php?s/?a=1&o=2`. Another three text boxes. If we enter three values the above url will change like `http://localhost/Send/test.php?s/?a=1&o=2&s1=a&s2=b&s3=c` . The value for `s1,s2` and `s3` will not save anywhere. My question is how we check is the value for `s1` is already set? And how can I update the value of `s1` if iI change the textbox value for `s1`[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace using this regex

```
url.replace(/&s1=([^$]+|[^&]+)/i, "&s1=newvalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guest you use PCRE in PHP:

```
(?=(?P<ES1>.*&s1=)?)(?(ES1)RegexToMatchIfS1AlreadyExist|RegexToMatchIfS1NotExist)
```

So

```
$result = preg_replace('/^(?=(?P<ES1>.*&s1=)?)(?(ES1)(?P<Left>.*&s1=)(?P<Right>.*+)$|RegexToMatchIfS1NotExist)/', '${1}newvalue${2}', ...);
```

Comment: If you don't need to take different action on which the &s1= exists or not, I think @BrunoLM's answer is prefered.

Comment: i need to check is s1 is exist or not

Answer (score 0):

use  this  secure regular expression for every language...

```
^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?[a-z0-9+\$_-]+(\.[a-z0-9+\$_-]+)*(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@/&%=+\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?\$
```